# can convert "bool" into " const char" error and misplaced else error c++

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++. I got an `can't convert"bool" into "const char"` error and the most annoying error i can run the "first strcmp". After that i got the error. I tried to fix it but if i did that it show lot of error. I'm stuck here dont know what to do.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{
 char kode[6][12],merk[15];
 int  j,a,mobil[6],banyak[6];
 long harga[6];

cout<<"\t\t\t|----------------------------|"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t|***Rental mobil sederhana***|"<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t| ***Jl. Tebet raya no.15*** | "<<endl;
cout<<"\t\t\t|----------------------------|"<<endl;
cout<<" "<<endl;
cout<<"merk mobil yang tersedia : 1. DAIHATSU Kode : DA"<<endl;
cout<<"                           2. TOYOTA   Kode : TO"<<endl;
cout<<"                           3. HONDA    Kode : HO"<<endl;
cout<<"Banyak mobil yang ingin disewa : "; cin>>j;
banyak[j]=0;
if(j<=0)
{
 for(a=1;a<=j; a++)
 {
  cout<<"Mobil ke   :"<<a<<endl;
  cout<<"kode merk :"; cin>>kode[a];
  cout<<"-------------"<<endl;
   if(strcmp(kode[a],"HO")==0 ||strcmp(kode[a],"ho")==0)
   {
     strcpy(merk,"HONDA");
     cout<<"1. Honda Mobilio = Rp.600.000/hari"<<endl;
     cout<<"2. Honda Jazz    = Rp.400.000/hari"<<endl;
     cout<<"3. Honda Civic   = Rp.700.000/hari"<<endl;
     cout<<"4. Honda Brio    = Rp.500.000/hari"<<endl;
     cout<<"masukan angka mobil :"; cin>>mobil[a];
     if(mobil[a]==1)
     harga[a]=600000;
     else if(mobil[a]==2)
     harga[a]=400000;
     else if(mobil[a]==3)
     harga[a]=700000;
     else if(mobil[a]==4)
     harga[a]=500000;
     }
   else if(strcmp(kode[a],"TO")==0 ||strcmp(kode[a],"to"==0) <<<<<here is where the error
   {
     strcpy(merk,"TOYOTA");
     cout<<"1. Toyota Innova = Rp.500.000/hari"<<endl;
     cout<<"2. Toyota Avanza = Rp.300.000/hari"<<endl;
     cout<<"3. Toyota Yaris  = Rp.350.000/hari"<<endl;
     cout<<"4. Toyota Veloz  = Rp.450.000/hari"<<endl;
```

Comment: Look at the line where the error is. Look where your parentheses and comparisons are.

Comment: @hivert its alredy solved right now,thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo

```
else if(strcmp(kode[a],"TO")==0 ||strcmp(kode[a],"to"==0)
```

It seems you mean

```
else if( strcmp( kode[a], "TO" ) == 0 || strcmp( kode[a], "to" ) == 0 )
```

Pay attention to that the order of these statements

```
cout<<"Banyak mobil yang ingin disewa : "; cin>>j;
banyak[j]=0;
if(j<=0)
```

is wrong. If indeed `j < 0` then the above statement

```
banyak[j]=0;
```

invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: thanks! my code works now its because im forget to add "if" above and that typo you say.but where i was wrong on "banyak[ j ]=0;?

Comment: @deltas As i already wrote in my answer if j < 0 then there is an attempt to access memory beyond the array.